# How to get rid of lizards from home?

Tags: home

There are many lizards in my home. And it seems like they have given birth to young ones. I have tried keeping peacock's feather. But it doesn't seem to have any effect on them. Are there any other ways to keep the lizards out of my home?

Comment: Pest control questions are on topic on Home Improvement.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to find out how they are entering your home and fix this issue. What type of lizard are they? Knowing this will help in specifics regarding removal, as you will also need to eliminate food sources. Here is a good guide:
http://www.getridofthings.com/pests/animals/get-rid-of-lizards/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.
You close all door in your home and window and If you find the lizards you can spray water to it. If it doesn't work you can follow this guide [for escape lizards](http://www.homeremediescare.com/16-easy-and-efficient-home-remedies-to-get-rid-of-lizards-infestation/)